# Key.der funciona bien en java pero en python y nodejs no hace bien el cifrado

Tags: java, python

Estoy implementando un código en java donde leo una llave privada para encriptar una cadena y trabaja perfectamente pero al querer replicar la función en python entonces el encriptado no trabaja bien y sin importar cual cadena sea el resultado del encriptado es "01". ¿A qué se puede deber esto?

**Código en Java**

```
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        System.out.println("Leyendo Llave Privada: " + arg[0]);
        byte[] bytesPv = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        System.out.println(byteArrayToHexString(bytesPv));
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytesPv);
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) 
        keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey );
        byte[] cadeToCipher = ( arg[3].equalsIgnoreCase("1") ) ? 
        hexStringToByteArray(arg[2]) : arg[2].getBytes();
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal( cadeToCipher );
        System.out.println("Cadena Cifrada: " + 
        byteArrayToHexString(cipherData).toUpperCase());
```

**Código en python**

```
rsa_key=RSA.importKey(der);
print("MODULO",rsa_key.n);
print("EXP PRIVADO",rsa_key.d);
print("EXP PUBLICO",rsa_key.e);
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(rsa_key)
encriptado = cipher.encrypt(DatosToken.encode()).hex();
```